# how to use an atomic vector as a string for a graph title in R

Tags: string, r, graph, atomic-values

I'm trying to plot a graph from a matrix of z-scores in R, i would like to build a function to iterate through each column using the column header as part of the title and saving each graph as a png.I think I know how to do the iteration and saving graphs as pngs but I am getting stuck with using the vector as a string. I tried to upload the matrix with no column headers and then store matrix[1,] as a variable 'headers' to use. Then I tried to plot:

```
 plot(1:30, rnorm(30), ylim=c(-10,10), yaxs="i", xlab = "Region", ylab = "Z-Score",main = "CNV plot of " + headers[i], type = "n")
```

I get:

```
 Warning message:
 In Ops.factor(left, right) : + not meaningful for factors
```

I try without the '+' and it says:

```
 Error: unexpected symbol in ...
```

So then I looked around and found 'paste(headers[i],collapse=" ") which I though I could substitute in but it just puts the number '28' as the title.

I've tried what I thought was another potential solution:

```
 plot(1:30, rnorm(30), ylim=c(-10,10), yaxs="i", xlab = "Region", ylab = "Z-Score",main = "Z-scores of " $headers[i], type = "n")
```

and I get:

```
 Error in "Z-scores of "$headers : 
 $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I'm new to R and this seems like something that would be so simple if I happened to stumble across the right guide/tutorial after hours of google searching but I really don't have that kind of time on my hands. Any suggestions, pointers or solutions would be great??

Comment: What is the expected plot title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert values from variables into strings for a plot title, `bquote` is the way to go:

```
headers <- c(28, 14, 7) # an examle
i <- 1

plot(1:30, rnorm(30), ylim=c(-10,10), yaxs="i",
     xlab = "Region", ylab = "Z-Score", type = "n",
     main = bquote("CNV plot of" ~ .(headers[i])) )
```

[image]

Have a look at the help page of `?bquote` for further information.

Answer (score 2):

`paste("CNV plot of", headers[i])`, should work.  You only need `collapse` if you are pasting vectors of length greater than one (`headers[i]` should be one length, even if `header` is not).  R doesn't have any concatenation operators, unlike PHP, JS, etc (so `+`, `&`, `.` will not work, you have to use `paste`).

Note that your paste was `paste(headers[i],collapse=" ")`, and if that just plotted `28`, it suggests your `headers` vector doesn't contain what you think it does (if you didn't want `28` to be displayed, that is.

Try just looping through your vector and printing the paste command to screen to see what it displays (and also, just print the vector).

Comment: thanks! paste("CNV plot of ", headers[i]) looks like its pretty much there but it seems to print '28' into the title still. however if I just type headers[i] to the console it prints the name that I want. Seems off why it doesn't print consistently when used in different contexts

Comment: @user3062260, try `as.character(headers[i])` inside `paste`, though it really should work as is.